# Deploy goal fails in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, deployment

I'm facing a rather weird issue in Netbeans at the moment. When attempting to deploy a maven project to an external repository in Netbeans I get a:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin...... Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.

I've set up a maven project in netbeans and added a custom build goal to deploy (using `mvn deploy`). All works well until the deploy stage where the actual deploy is failing. The repository I use has a username/password combination required which has been defined in my `settings.xml` file for Maven and **deploying using the command line works without issue** (i.e. I open command prompt and type `mvn deploy` in the project directory and I get a build success).

After some experimenting I determined that when netbeans calls maven for building, the `settings.xml` file is somehow not being read. I've tried putting the settings file in my `user.home\.m2\` directory as well without success. Am I missing something or is this just a bug with netbeans?

Netbeans is running:

`mvn -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"<path to netbeans>\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" deploy`

and everything works until the deploy stage.

**Edit:**

I've tried switching from the bunched maven that netbeans provides to my personal installation with no avail.

I am running Windows 7 x84-64.

Answer (score 0):

which settings.xml file are we talking about? there's one called "user" settings file placed in ~/.m2/ and then there's another one that is called "global" I think which resides in $M2_HOME/conf/ and is part of the installation. If netbeans is not picking up your global settings file, then it's likely because it's using a different maven installation than your command line (by default netbeans uses it's own copy).

Try setting your usual maven installation as the one to be used by netbeans (Tools/Options -> Java/Maven or similar based on the version you are using)

copying you settings.xml to ~/.m2/settings.xml should have worked as well, I suppose you've done something wrong, or netbeans is pointed at different java.lang.System.getProperty("user.home")

Comment: Tried both (bundled/separately installed). Also tried both putting the settings.xml in the user.home\.m2 dir and the "global" install dir (as mentioned in the question). I highly doubt netbeans doesn't know where my user.home is... I've never done anything to change that.

Comment: if this were a general issue, I guess it would have been filed in nb.org bugzilla for a while but I've never heard of the problem before. Did running with debug switches on reveal anything?

Comment: somewhere in the beginning of the output should be the path where maven looks for settings. what platform are you on?

Comment: I am running on Windows 7 x86-64. Full debug log is just spam of the same message with stack trace thats essentially useless. The output log shows that its reading the global/user settings.xml from the right place.